# Object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to compile a simple scala program and I'm using StreamingContext , here is a snippet of my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerStageCompleted
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ //error:object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
object FileCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("File Count")
    .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10)) //error : not found: type StreamingContext
    sc.stop()    
  }
}
```

I have these two error:

```
object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
```

and

```
not found: type StreamingContext
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the dependency of spark-streaming into your build manager.

Comment: may i know the dependency name for sbt file.

Comment: Depending on what version of Scala and Spark, check out the [mvn repo info](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **sbt**, add the following library dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

If you are using **maven**, add the below to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added missing dependency after that its work for me, which are

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % SparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the correct dependency corresponds to your `import` statement. And hope obviously you have import the `spark-streaming` dependencies. except that we need this dependency also.

Here are the dependencies based on your dependency management tool.

**For Maven : Add following to pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**For SBT : Add following to build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

---

**For Gradle**

```
provided group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.11', version: '2.1.0'
```

---

**TIP** : use [grepcode.com](http://www.grepcode.com/) to find the appropriate dependency by searching your import statement. It is a nite site!

**NOTE** : dependency versions can be changed & updated with the time.